# Can't customized the android icon and text in a tab

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I am working with an android tabhost, the problem is , I would like to customized the text and the icon of the tab, but in my attempt the outcome is just one icon and unclickable too. Are there any problem in my code? Thanks for helping

```
tabHost.setup(ctx, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    for (String tag : tags) {
                if (tag.equals("home")) {
                    tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, tabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
                    ((TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon_txt)).setText("news");
                    ((ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageResource(R.drawable.test_menu);
                    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabIndicator),Home.class, null);
                } else if (tag.equals("news")) {
                    tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, tabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
                    ((TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon_txt)).setText("news");
                    ((ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageResource(R.drawable.test_menu);
                    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabIndicator),NewsFragment.class, null);
                } else if (tag.equals("info")) {
                    tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, tabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
                    ((TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon_txt)).setText("news");
                    ((ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageResource(R.drawable.test_menu);
                    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabIndicator),InfoFragment.class, null);
                } else {
                    tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, tabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
                    ((TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon_txt)).setText("news");
                    ((ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageResource(R.drawable.test_menu);
                    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabIndicator),PageFragment.class, null);
                }
            }
tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
```

And the xml to customize the tab

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/icon_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Don't understand why tabs became so difficult.  Android screwed this up.  Why can't I just add text or just use an icon for the tabs using only XML?  Why do I have to write code and set Indicators and create selectors?  Is there a better option than TabHost or FragmentTabHost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the demonstrated implementation provided in the following link. I am sure that it will solve your problem :)

http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2012/10/27/android-styling-the-tabs-in-a-tabwidget/

It provides an implementation of customised TabWidget. 
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check this sample project it shows you how to change colour and other things you can find with other samples.
  [Click here](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/index.html)

Hope this will help you :)